# How to remove square brackets and apostrophe from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have printed each list element to a new line but cannot manage how to remove the square brackets and apostrophes.

This is my output:

```
Statement:
Initial balance                 100.0     
event                amount ($) balance ($)
['Ride                 3.5        96.5      ']
['Ride                 10.9       85.6      ']
['Top Up               20.0       105.6     ']
Final balance                   105.6
```

this is how I am adding stuff to my lists:

```
transaction = [("{:<20} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Top Up', amount, self.balance))]
self.statement.append(transaction)
```

and this is how I am printing my lists to newline:

```
print(*self.statement, sep='\n')
```

Thankyou

Comment: Use `.extend` instead of `.append`.

Comment: `transaction` is a `list` with one element, which is `str`.  This is what you create. Why are you surprised with the output? why do you create `transaction` as a `list` in the first place?

Comment: @AndrewMizuno Actually that's not a proper solution. Better make `transaction` a string if you are not using it anywhere else: `transaction = "{:<20} ...".format(...)` and keep using `append`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code 'transaction' is a list item. This means you are adding a list to 'self.statements' creating a nested list. Instead 'transaction' should be a string item like so.

```
transaction = "{:<20} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Top Up', amount, self.balance)
```